# How to login the super user(root) in remote host system using pexpect?

Tags: pexpect

How to login the super user(root) in remote host system using pexpect?

```
user = root user
password = 'pass'
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s'%(user,host,))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will get answer

```
child = pexpext.spawn('ssh root@host')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply log in to a user on ssh like normal,
then send commands to log into the root like you normally would in a terminal.

```
#log into user account
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh clientuser@localhost')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('password')
#then log into root account
child.sendline('su')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('sudopassword1234')
```

This is just longer and more code, and probably only works on linux the way i wrote it. But you could use this if directly ssh to root doesn't work.