# error in pexpect script to login as root

Tags: python-2.x, pexpect

import pexpect, os, sys

cmd = "sudo su -"

p = pexpect.spawn(cmd, timeout=60)

pass_expect = ".*assword.*" (as I get a prompt saying "[sudo] password for user" )

p.expect(pass_expect)

print "I want the password"

p.sendline("mypassword")

p.logfile = sys.stdout

p.sendline("logout")

p.close()

I am getting the following error while executing the above script

**Error**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 11, in 
    p.expect(pass_expect)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect

```
return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list

```
return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop

```
raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
```

pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().

version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)

command: /usr/bin/sudo

args: ['/usr/bin/sudo', 'su', '-']

searcher: searcher_re:

```
0: re.compile(".*assword.*")
```

buffer (last 100 chars): root@:~#

before (last 100 chars): root@:~#

after:

match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 16933
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 60

delimiter: 
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1

Can someone please help me out as I am been stuck in this problem from few days.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If you login as a superuser means put **root@localhost**

```
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh root@localhost")
child.logfile = open("/tmp/mylog", "w")
child.expect(".*assword:")
child.send("guest\r")
child.expect(".*\$ ")
child.sendline("python -V\r")
print child.before
```

[How to login the super user(root) in remote host system using pexpect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895847/how-to-login-the-super-userroot-in-remote-host-system-using-pexpect)